# I get a null pointer exception error every time that I try to get an offline player

Tags: java, bukkit

Every time that I try to right-click a head with the name of an offline player, it just returns a console error and nothing happens. If the target player of the player head is online, the event will work perfectly.

Error:

```
org.bukkit.event.EventException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:305) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.event.CraftEventFactory.callPlayerInteractEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:226) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.event.CraftEventFactory.callPlayerInteractEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:193) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.event.CraftEventFactory.callPlayerInteractEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:189) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1153) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PacketPlayInArmAnimation.a(SourceFile:22) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PacketPlayInArmAnimation.a(SourceFile:8) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.PacketHandleTask.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.z(MinecraftServer.java:696) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.z(DedicatedServer.java:316) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.y(MinecraftServer.java:634) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:537) [spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.milkbowl.vault.economy.AbstractEconomy.getBalance(AbstractEconomy.java:20) ~[?:?]
        at me.rarfiles.hyrushbounties.Events.onItemClick(Events.java:69) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:301) ~[spigot-1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        ... 17 more
```

My main code:
https://pastebin.com/30MaKgrD

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add actual working code rather than providing a link. (`economy` is NULL, but we don't have enough context to tell why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(name);
```

Returns a player if he is online and not an offline player.

```
Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer()
```

This gives you the offlinePlayer.